# Struggling to understand error propagation using a Result<_, _>

Tags: rust, error-handling, actix-web

I want to write a function that intercepts the `HttpRequest` of an actix-web route handler. In the function, I want to extract the Authorization header JWT and decode it. If it succeeds, I want to return the claims. If not, I want to send a 401 response and return an error:

```rust
fn extract_jwt(req: HttpRequest) -> Result<TokenData<Claims>, anyhow::Error> {
    // forgive me my unwraps
    let authorization_header = req
        .headers()
        .get("Authorization")
        .unwrap()
        .to_str()
        .unwrap();
    let token = authorization_header
        .split_whitespace()
        .collect::<Vec<&str>>()[1];

    let key = DecodingKey::from_secret(&[]);
    let mut validation = Validation::new(Algorithm::HS256);
    validation.insecure_disable_signature_validation();
    validation.set_audience(&["account"]);

    match decode::<Claims>(&token, &key, &validation) {
        Ok(claims) => Ok(claims),
        Err(e) => {
            HttpResponse::Unauthorized().finish();
            anyhow::Error("Could not decode JWT: {:?}", e) // error here
        }
    }
}
```

In my `match` arms, I return either the `claims`, which is the `TokenData<Claims>` of the `Result`, and Rust is happy with that. But for the `Err` arm, I get the error:

```
expected function, tuple struct or tuple variant, found struct `anyhow::Error`
```

Clearly I am not understanding how to propagate this error back to the caller. For example, in any given route, I want to extract the JWT with this function:

```rust
#[get("/some/route")]
async fn get_things(req: HttpRequest) {
  if let claims = extract_jwt(req) {
    // Handle the route logic here
    // If there is an error in extract_jwt, it should handle sending the response
    // as Unauthorized, so there is no need for an `else` statement here
  }
}
```

Despite pouring over the Rust docs about `match` statements, the `Result` enum, and propagating errors, I haven't found the right combination to set this up right. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`anyhow::Error` is a struct with private fields, so you can't construct it directly. In other words `anyhow::Error("Could not decode JWT: {:?}", e)` is invalid code.

Because you use a `println` like syntax it's likely you meant to use the macro [`anyhow::anyhow`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/macro.anyhow.html) instead.

That leaves another problem still, your function returns a `Result` that means any returned value has to be constructed with either `Ok()` or `Err()`. So you'll have to add that as well.

TL;DR replace `anyhow::Error("Could not decode JWT: {:?}", e)` with `Err(anyhow::anyhow!("Could not decode JWT: {:?}", e))`